# how to create HTML dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, menu

my purpose is when i click Season , show dropdown menu for example season1,season2
how can do this ? this is my html code

```html
<ul class="video-meta">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="assets/images/6b1345063abbc415fde0677567f2cf59.jpg" alt="Bayley"></a>
    <span class="pl-10"> Bayley</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>1260 Views
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fas fa-tags"></i> <a href="archive.html">Season</a></li>
  <li>
    <i class="fas fa-photo-video"></i> 2 h 20 min
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> Nov 2020
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fas fa-film"></i> 4K
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the [select](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-select-element) tag for drop-downs with an option for each of the values.

```html
<select name=season>
  <option>Season 1
  <option>Season 2
  <option>Season 3
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<select>` tag in HTML to create a dropdown menu.

```
   <label for="seasons">Season:</label>
   <select name="seasons" id="seasons">
     <option value="Season1">Season1</option>
     <option value="Season2">Season2</option>
     <option value="Season3">Season3</option>
   </select>
```

The `value=` property is what will be sent to the server when the data is submitted.

Comment: it's damage css , how can i do this not to change class name ?

Comment: This 
<li>
                                    <i class="fas fa-tags"></i> <a href="archive.html">Action</a></li>
                                <li>